# how to give print option to pdf file after generating in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have pdf file in my application. I need to display the pdf in browser. and also need to give print option to that page for printing how is it possible in servlet.i am generating pdf but how to give the print option to that generated pdf

Comment: Doesn't the  PDF opened in browser has its own print option ?

Answer (score 1):

I think `javascript` should help You.

Use `window.print()`

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp

Comment: Note that PDF cannot contain JS (or if it does, any browser would ignore it).  So to work, this would need to be invoked from HTML in another frame of a frame set.